# Count number of posts per author in Jekyll

Tags: markdown, jekyll, liquid, jekyll-extensions

I just can't work out how to display a number of articles for each author on a list of authors page.

Author 1 - 4 articles

Author 2 - 3 articles

Author 3 - 5 articles

Any ideas please? Thank you

Comment: Enumerate through all posts `{% for post in site.posts %}` and make a counter for each author.

Comment: If you can use plugins, drop a Ruby script into `_plugins/` is the fastest and easiest way to do that.